# Where on the web can I find a calendar of upcoming contests?

Tags: contest, internet

For years, I have been using [SM3CER Contest Service](http://www.sk3bg.se/contest/index.htm) for HF contests.

It is always good to have a backup, so I am looking for more or better.

What do *you* recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the [WA7BNM Contest Calendar](http://www.hornucopia.com/contestcal/index.html), usually the 8 Day version is enough for me, I can't plan much farther in advance. This one is nice with links to the rules and such so I check it regularly.  There is also the [ARRL Contest Calendar](http://www.arrl.org/contest-calendar), it usually only has the ARRL sponsored contests though.  And there is always the handy [3830 Scores](http://www.3830scores.com/index.php) site for the post contest chest-beating :). But the quickest way to get a sense of how you did.

Comment: The ARRL Contest Corral also lists non-ARRL contests for each month

Comment: [The graphic timetable representation](http://www.hornucopia.com/contestcal/weeklycont.php) in the week view of the WA7BNM Contest Calendar is really nice and conveys a lot of information at the glance of an eye.

Answer (score 2):

The [PG7V HF Contest Calendar](http://www.cqcontest.eu/) is also a nice one.

In the meantime, I have put up a [web page linking to all the calendars](http://hamwaves.com/contests/en/index.html) mentioned in these answers.